# can't find my users AspNetUsers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I've moved all the tables,

```
AspNetRoles
AspNetUserClaims
AspNetLogins
AspNetRoles
AspNetUsers
```

into my working SQL Server 2012 Express database with the rest of my tables and updated my `.EDMX` in Visual Studio Express 2013. I can now see all my tables and all my models in one place in VS.

When I create a new user everything works fine but the new users are not ending up in the AspNetUsers table in the database. Like I said, the application continues to work fine with the new user but I can't find them anywhere, where are they?
I only have one connection string in my application, so I have no idea where or why they could be going anywhere else:

```
<add name="Entities" 
connectionString=
  "metadata=res://*/Models.Listing.csdl|res://*/Models.Listing.ssdl|res://*/Models.Listing.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXXXXXXX;initial catalog=database;
integrated security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The new user is somewhere, after creating one I can navigate. Could they just be stuck in memory or something?

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: Did you change the connection string for the accounts so it points to the right server/database? If you didn't specify an account connection string it'll use the default connection string in web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new user is probably sitting in the database specified in your default connection string in your web.config.  Make sure to specify the connection string named "Entities".

I'm guessing but I would tend to believe that they are being saved in a LocalDB file specified by your default connection string.

Comment: I found them, thanks. EF has created a database called DefaultConnection even though I haven't specified that in my connection string I will now change the name of it and see what happens. It's probably built it at an earlier stage when the connection string was there?